# Object Constraint menus and data Not showing up once constraint is added

Tags: constraints

in 2.79b, when I add a constraint to anything no additional edit menus appear.  Usually, and I checked this with a version at the school I teach for, a constraint menu will appear under "ADD OBJECT CONSTRAINT" once the constraint is added.  Nothing appears.  So I cannot use constraints and this is a problem since I have several rigs that need rigging and the constraints are not showing up to complete the rigs.

I had constraints a few months ago, the last time I needed to use them, but now they are not showing up.  Is there something that can make constraints not run?  Are there addons that prevent the constraints from running properly?

Thank you for any help you can provide.
[image]

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use the tools from this site to upload images so that they are displayed as part of your question. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: Could it be that the options you want appear in the floating panel, bottom left of the 3D view?

Comment: it does not want to add any more than one image, but the one is enough since the constraint menu looks identical before and after I add a constraint.  In this example I added the dampened track constraint so the plane will follow the camera as it tracks.  However, as you can see there is no data to work with.  Also, I added the constraint in 2.8, brought it back over to 2.79 to see if I would have data in the constraints tab, and the file just crashes.   

ANY HELP PLEASE...THANK YOU.

Comment: I tried other windows to see if the constraint data would be in any of them, the menus do not appear anywhere.